# Twitter and Recent Tweets Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

Getting frustrated with the Twitter gem.

In my gemfile I placed

```
gem 'twitter'
```

I created an initializer, twitter_credentials.rb file where I've placed the following code:

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = 'foo'
  config.consumer_secret = 'bar'
  config.access_token = 'foo'
  config.access_token_secret = 'bar'
end
```

Now I'm trying to access the tweets from the account these credentials belong to.  I'd like to do something in the application controller like:

```
@tweets = client.tweets
```

but the client above results in a name error.  How do I access the tweets of a user?  It used to be

```
@tweets = Twitter.user_timeline('user_name')
```

but I suppose that's been removed.  Please don't tell me to look at sferiks documentation, as I've looked at that and it doesn't make sense to me, as client.(anything) will result in a NameError

What do I have to do to get a list of tweets?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue a few months ago. I believe you have a scope issue. I placed the call to get tweets in the same module that I created the client in.

```
module TwitterApi

  def get_tweets(twittername)
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = ENV['CONSUMER_KEY']
      config.consumer_secret     = ENV['CONSUMER_SECRET']
      config.access_token        = ENV['ACCESS_TOKEN']
      config.access_token_secret = ENV['ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET']
    end

    tweets = client.user_timeline(twittername)
  end
end
```

This way your twitter call will return the tweet array, and you don't have to worry about scope issues. In you controller:

```
class Foo 
  include TwitterApi

  def bar
    @tweets = get_tweets('username')
  end
end
```

This worked for me. I hope it helps.